# Enter password in dialog/prompt

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

How do I enter password in the browser alert/dialog window. It is displayed when the url is loaded. It is not a basic auth prompt but a password prompt which blocks any interaction with the page until password is entered. I am using selenium ruby with Capybara. I have tried the following:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.send_keys("Password")
```

but it doesn't enter anything

[image: Prompt screenshot]

Comment: So what did you tried ?

Comment: Tried like this if it is an alert `Alert alert =driver.switchTo().alert();  alert.sendKeys("text"); alert.accept();`

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have tried so far which is similar to what you've suggested but didn't work

Comment: Are you seeing any HTML by inspecting the textbox of given popup ? or its a javascript alert ?

Comment: No html. Its a browser alert

Comment: This looks like .htaccess basic authorization. This is probably not targetable but @AnkurSingh's answer should put you on the right track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're trying to fill in is a system modal triggered by JS `window.prompt` then you can handle it like

```
page.accept_prompt(with: "The text to fill in") do
  page.click_button "Go" # whatever action triggers the prompt to appear
end
```

If instead it's a system authentication modal (not opened by JS) then you can't access it from Capybara, and will have to use a full system automation tool specific for the platform you're using if you can't pass the credentials in the URL you're attempting to access.

By the way, if you want many prompts in a row, you can encapsulate them:

```
page.accept_prompt("A prompt", with: "X") do
  page.accept_prompt("Another prompt", with: "Y") do
    page.click_button "Go" # Triggers two prompts
  end
end
```

The first parameter of `accept_prompt` (`"A prompt"` resp. `"Another prompt"` in the code above) is optional; if you provide it the modals text will be checked for a match with the parameter, and will error if it doesn't match. The order the prompts are expected to appear would be inside out of the blocks (first 'another prompt' then 'prompt')

Comment: what about using some javascript/jquery `page.execute_script(SIMULATE KEYPRESS)`?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I didn't realise that text can be passed in via "with:" option. It worked but I don't see the text filled in. I had previously tried send_keys which also didn't seem to fill in the text in the prompt which made me look for another option. Both work but text doesn't appear filled in. Anyway, what you suggested worked.

Comment: @fabersky If you're referring to the case of it being a system modal not opened by JS, generally you can't execute anything once one opens.

Comment: What if there are multiple prompts triggered with the same action? EDIT: it's possible to encapsulate them like this: `page.accept_prompt with: "X" { page.accept_prompt with: "Y" { ... } }`. Feels a bit quirky, but it works.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim Note: if you wanted to verify the text of the actuals prompts it would be `page.accept_prompt "blah blah", with: "X" { page.accept_prompt "other blah blah", with: "Y" }`

Comment: This is very useful information, Thomas! I wonder whether we should create a new answer from this information?

Comment: For the records: I added the info to the current answer.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim Specifying the text doesn't change the order they are processed in - it just verifies that text is shown in the box (and errors if a box that doesn't match is shown)

Answer (score 2):

This may help you :

```
  String Password = URLEncoder.encode("pass");

  String UserName= URLEncoder.encode("UserName");

  String url = String.format("http://%s:%s@xyz",
                        UserName, Password);
```

In this `%s` is variable which pass to url  in form of parameter.

You can refer to [this url](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters) also.

Comment: this answer isn't very helpful and doesn't answer the question at all.